# standard operating procedure for pen test

Tags: penetration-test

I have been asked to create a Standard Operating Procedure (SOP), to describe the phases of: 
intelligence gathering, target profiling, vulnerability identification, target exploitation and post exploitation

I know what a standard operating procedure is but have no idea on how to create one.

Any chance you can help me to create one for these phases only?

Note: I am not asking you to do it for me instead I am asking for a tutorial or a guide you may know of or have come across which I can use to do it myself for these phases...thank you

Comment: Here is the [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/419921main_ITS-HB_0017-A_.pdf) SOP for pentesting. That'll give you a guideline of how you should approach yours.

Comment: I sometimes wonder whether such standard procedures shouldn't be "best practices" guides for network admins, that one should much rather check in cooperation with those admins, and use non-standardized (read: admins don't "optimize" for these) methods for pen-testing. Everything else feels like "teaching kids to perform well in exams" rather than "learning for life".

Answer (score 1):

[Special Publication 800-115 Technical Guide to Information Security Testing and Assessment](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-115.pdf) will help you in creating an SOP for security testing.

Comment: thank you its very detailed for a newbie ....how would i describe the phases of: intelligence gathering, target profiling, vulnerability identification, target exploitation and post exploitation in a SOP? I thought a SOP gave you instructions on how to do it rather then what it is?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **Penetration Testing Execution Standard (PTES)**.

**PTES** defines penetration testing through 7 phases:

1. Pre-engagement Interactions
2. Intelligence Gathering
3. Threat Modeling
4. Vulnerability Analysis
5. Exploitation
6. Post Exploitation
7. Reporting

This guide covers all 7 phases of the penetration testing process in great detail:

http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/PTES_Technical_Guidelines

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Open Source Security Testing Methodology Manual (OSSTMM)
- http://www.isecom.org/research/osstmm.html